# Resizeable WPF ListBox / ItemsControl items

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemscontrol, listboxitem, gridsplitter

I would like to have GridSplitter-like functionality in a WPF ListBox (or ItemsControl). The following code doesn't work but demonstrates what I want to achieve:

```
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

              <GridSplitter
                Width="5"
                Background="Red"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                ResizeBehavior="CurrentAndNext"/>

           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this?

Comment: A GridSplitter will resize rows/columns within a Grid.  Your code has one grid with one row and one column for each list box item.  The splitter won't do anything.

Comment: @Phil: correct, in this scenario the splitter doesn't work, but I'm looking for a way to make it work

Comment: ok, but what are expecting it to do? It's not obvious.  BalamBalam seems to have a good answer if you're looking for resizable columns.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use ListView GridView?  GridView supports resizing columns.

Comment: Hm maybe that could work, I'd have to hide the columns and enable resizing the cells, or maybe only show the columns. But the cells would have to be created using multiple items in the source collection so I'm not sure this would work when binding to one collection

Comment: A ListView and a ListBox are both repeater controls.  What is the fundamental difference?